# Not able to commit a local file to my Github repo

Tags: python, git, github

**I'm using Raspbian and python 2.7.9. I cloned ,my repo(Test-git) and I wrote the below code to commit and push the changes to a file(test_1.csv) to my Github 
repo. Below is my code:**

```
from github import Github
import git

g = Github("22c34f753fc0e78c051ada0c622elwjwkjfkwhf")
for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
    print(repo.name)

repo = git.Repo.init('/home/pi/Desktop/Test-git')

file = '/home/pi/Desktop/Test-git/test_1.csv' #path to file to push

repo.git.add(file) 

repo.git.commit(m = "commit message") 

repo.git.push('Test-git', 'HEAD:master')
```

**But I receive the below error :**

```
  repo.git.commit(m = "commit message") 

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git/cmd.py", line 551, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git/cmd.py", line 1010, in _call_process
    return self.execute(call, **exec_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git/cmd.py", line 821, in execute
    raise GitCommandError(command, status, stderr_value, stdout_value)
GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
  cmdline: git commit -m commit message
  stdout: 'On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   README.md

Untracked files:
    Doc/
    MA_token_2.py
    New.csv

no changes added to commit'
```

Comment: Could you add which modules you have installed that provide `git`? In addition, could you verify that this problem isn't that the file doesn't exist? Do `touch test_1.csv` and then run your script. For now, I suspect that's the problem because the git error message doesn't mention that file in the untracked files either.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I modified the repo a little and I'm receiving this new error below. I tried to modify the README.md file and push the changes. I received an error as below that I do not know how to interpret it.

Comment: remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository        
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent        
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match        
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.

Comment: ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git_test'